# Getting only Month and Year from SQL DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to access only Month.Year from Date field in SQL Server.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

As well as the suggestions given already, there is one other possiblity I can infer from your question:
- You still want the result to be a date
- But you want to 'discard' the Days, Hours, etc
- Leaving a year/month only date field

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, <dateField>), 0) AS [year_month_date_field]
FROM
   <your_table>
```

This gets the number of whole months from a base date (0) and then adds them to that base date.  Thus rounding Down to the month in which the date is in.

NOTE: In SQL Server 2008, You will still have the TIME attached as 00:00:00.000
This is not exactly the same as "removing" any notation of day and time altogether.
Also the DAY set to the first. e.g. 2009-10-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: This didn't work at all for me. It gives me 2023-02-01 00:00:00.000 as the result.

Comment: @dss - with what parameters?  Show the actual SQL and I'm happy to have a look.

Comment: @MatBailie SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, LastSaleDate), 0) AS [year_month_date_field] FROM db1.products where productID = 123

The "LastSaleDate" column is declared as "(datetime, not null)"

and I get: 2014-09-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: @DSS - Yes, that appears to be correct.  It's rounding down to the very start of September 2014.  There is no "Year and Month only" data type, so using the first moment of each month is the standard practice.  When converting this DATETIME value to a string (Aaplication Layer, Presentation Layer, Reporting Layer, etc), you can always choose to format it with just the year and month parts.  But in terms of "in database" data manipulation this is correct.

Comment: I think maybe because your answer was meant to be used with a "Date" field but I'm using a "datetime" field so that's probably the issue.

Comment: @Dss - There is no difference in behaviour.  With a DATE data-type you get the first day of the month.  With a DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME data-type you get the first moment of the first day of the month.   `'2014-09-01 00:00:00.000' == '2014-09-01'`.  There is *no* data type that has a granularity of "month".  Thus this method exists to round the value down until the Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond, etc are all equal to "the start of the month".

Comment: @MatBailie Everything except the actual visual output. A datetime field will pad the result so while they may be functionally equivalent, when you are trying to pass a specific string into another programming language that expects xx/yy/zz then it chokes on xx/yy/zz-hh:mm:ss regardless of its equivalence.

Comment: @dss - Then you're trying to do the wrong thing.  This is about applying changes to a DATETIME data type, you're talking about about the string representation of such a datatype.  Note, DATETIMEs are *not* stored in the DB as text, they're stored as counters (one integer for the Date and another for the Time).  Just use `LEFT(<string>, 8)` if you need the first 8 characters only, and look at CONVERT for the different formats available for converting a DATETIME to a string.

Comment: Well what I am after is what the OP wants. But as I stated, my issue is due to using a Datetime field instead of a date field. In any case, the post below works perfectly for both cases.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing; unfortunately I couldn't get this to work in SSIS (Derived Column) but I found an alternative:  `DATEADD("DAY",-DAY(<dateField>)+1,<dateField>)` (remove quotes for "normal" SQL).

Answer (score 186):

```
select month(dateField), year(dateField)
```

Comment: great! You can connect them to one column: 'select cast(month(dateField) as varchar) + '.' + cast(year(dateField) as varchar)'

Answer (score 66):

```
SELECT convert(varchar(7), getdate(), 126)
```

You might wanna check out this website:
http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: @RuelosJoel varchar(6) would truncate "2021-03" to "2021-0"

Answer (score 37):

```
SELECT DATEPART(yy, DateVal)
SELECT DATEPART(MM, DateVal)
SELECT DATENAME(MM, DateVal)
```

Comment: SELECT DATEPART(MM, DateVal) is not returning 'MM'. Its just returning single digit if month is between 1-9.

Comment: Instead of "MM" it should say "month":  'SELECT DATEPART(month, getdate())'

Answer (score 20):

There are two SQL function to do it:

- [DATEPART()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql)
- [YEAR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql) and [MONTH()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql).

Refer to the linked documentation for details.

Comment: I'd suggest to put at least some brief examples because links don't always stay forever... In fact they are not good anymore.

Answer (score 20):

```
datename(m,column)+' '+cast(datepart(yyyy,column) as varchar) as MonthYear
```

the output will look like: 'December 2013'

Answer (score 19):

Some of the databases such as `MS ACCESS` or `RODBC` may not support the `SQL SERVER` functions, but for any database that has the `FORMAT` function you can simply do this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(<your-date-field>,"yyyy-MM") AS year-date FROM <your-table>
```

Comment: Exactly, the best and simple solution: select FORMAT(getdate(), 'MMyyyy')

Comment: Year's Y should be small like that y

Comment: @AsadNaeem in some languages small y is used to represent the 2-digit year, but in some other ones, it does not matter really. I changed it to small characters to be on the safe side

Answer (score 14):

This can be helpful as well.

```
SELECT YEAR(0), MONTH(0), DAY(0);
```

or

```
SELECT YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), DAY(getdate());
```

or

```
SELECT YEAR(yourDateField), MONTH(yourDateField), DAY(yourDateField);
```

Comment: Anyway to not remove the "0" in the return field?

Answer (score 12):

let's write it this way: `YEAR(anySqlDate)` and `MONTH(anySqlDate)`. Try it with `YEAR(GETDATE())` for example.

Answer (score 11):

```
convert(varchar(7), <date_field>, 120)
because 120 results in 'yyyy-MM-dd' which is varchar(10)
using varchar(7) will display only year and month

example:
select convert(varchar(7), <date_field>, 120), COUNT(*)
from <some_table>
group by convert(varchar(7), <date_field>, 120)
order by 1
```

Answer (score 7):

I am interpreting your question in two ways.

a) You only need Month & Year seperately in which case here is the answer

```
select 
        [YEAR] = YEAR(getdate())
        ,[YEAR] = DATEPART(YY,getdate())
        , [MONTH] = month(getdate())
        ,[MONTH] = DATEPART(mm,getdate())
        ,[MONTH NAME] = DATENAME(mm, getdate())
```

b)

You want to display from a given date say `'2009-11-24 09:01:55.483'` in **MONTH.YEAR** format. So the output should come as `11.2009` in this case.

If that is supposed to be the case then try this(among other alternatives)

```
select [Month.Year] = STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(),104),1,3,'')
```

Answer (score 7):

```
select CONCAT(MONTH(GETDATE()),'.',YEAR(GETDATE()))
Output: **5.2020**

select CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH , GETDATE()),'.',YEAR(GETDATE()))
Output: **May.2020**
```

Answer (score 5):

```
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), reg_dte, 105), 7)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
CONCAT (datepart (yy,DATE), FORMAT (DATE,'MM'))
```

gives you eg 201601 if you want a six digit result

Answer (score 5):

For MySQL, this works pretty well:

```
DATE_FORMAT(<your-date>, '%Y-%m %M')
```

It goes into the `SELECT` statement. Here's the output:

```
2014-03 March
```

For more information about `DATE_FORMAT`, check out the documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: The question is about MS SQL and this code is for MySQL. At least you should write an info about it.

Comment: @bafsar this page is the first result when searching with "sql" in the query, so I posted an answer here which worked for me

Comment: date_format(date, 'yyyy-MM-01') as month worked for me thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
select to_char(DATEFIELD,'MON') from YOUR_TABLE
```

eg.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'MON') from dual
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `SELECT CONCAT(month(datefield), '.', year(datefield)) FROM YOURTABLE;`

Answer (score 4):

For reporting purposes I tend to use

```
CONCAT(YEAR([DateColumn]), RIGHT(CONCAT('00', MONTH([DateColumn])), 2))
```

You will lose the date type, since that will return (n)varchar. But with the leading zero this column is sortable (e.g. '202112' > '202102'). You could also add a seperator between year and month like

```
CONCAT(YEAR([DateColumn]), '-', RIGHT(CONCAT('00', MONTH([DateColumn])), 2))
```

returning somethink like '2020-08' (still sortable).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Portuguese

```
SELECT format(dateadd(month, 0, getdate()), 'MMMM', 'pt-pt') + ' ' + convert(varchar(10),year(getdate()),100)
```

Result: 
maio 2019

---

English

```
SELECT format(dateadd(month, 0, getdate()), 'MMMM', 'en-US') + ' ' + convert(varchar(10),year(getdate()),100)
```

Result: 
May 2019

If you want in another language, change '**pt-pt**' or '**en-US**' to any of these in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

I had a specific requirement to do something similar where it would show month-year which can be done by the following:

`SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) + '-' +  CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS nvarchar) AS 'Month-Year'`

In my particular case, I needed to have it down to the 3 letter month abreviation with a 2 digit year, looking something like this: 
`SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(month, GETDATE()), 3) + '-' +  CAST(RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()),2) AS nvarchar(2)) AS 'Month-Year'`

Answer (score 2):

Another simple answer is to remove the number of day from the date

Here how to do it in BigQuery

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(<date_field>, INTERVAL 1 - extract(day from <date_field>) DAY) as year_month_date
```

An exemple :

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date '2021-03-25', INTERVAL 1 - extract(day from date '2021-03-25') DAY) as year_month_date
```

This return `2021-03-01`

Answer (score 0):

My database doesn't support most of the functions above however I found that this works:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTR(datetime_column, starting_position, number_of_strings)=required_year_and_month;`

for example:
`SELECT SUBSTR(created, 1,7) FROM table;`

returns the year and month in the format "yyyy-mm"

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(varchar(11), transfer_date, 106)
```

got me my desired result of date formatted as 07 Mar 2018

My column 'transfer_date' is a datetime type column and I am using SQL Server 2017 on azure

Answer (score 0):

For result: "YYYY-MM"

```
SELECT cast(YEAR(<DateColumn>) as varchar) + '-' + cast(Month(<DateColumn>) as varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Get Month & Year From Date***

```
DECLARE @lcMonth nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @lcYear nvarchar(10)

SET @lcYear=(SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,@Date))
SET @lcMonth=(SELECT  DATEPART(MONTH,@Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Query :-  `Select datename(m,GETDATE())+'-'+cast(datepart(yyyy,GETDATE()) as varchar) as FieldName`

Output :- January-2019

general datefield we can use

```
datename(m,<DateField>)+' '+cast(datepart(yyyy,<DateField>) as varchar) as FieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), 8), ' ', '-')
```

Output: Mar-2019

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM demo 
    WHERE attendance_year_month < SUBSTRING(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,11) 
          AND
          attendance_year_month >= DATE_SUB(SUBSTRING(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,11), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Function "Format" is a convenient and flexible, but there is a performance concern, [more details](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

If you are not very serious about formatting, grab year month by converting it as a string, the running time is acceptable as well

`SELECT substring(<DateColumn> as varchar) ,0, 8 ) as YearMonth`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may want to consider a computed column for this.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ClubMetadata ADD JoinYear AS YEAR(JoinDate);
ALTER TABLE dbo.ClubMetadata ADD JoinMonth AS MONTH(JoinDate);
```

This can be useful for readability and also if you want to index the data since deterministic computed columns can be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

select SubString(convert(varchar, getdate(), 0), 1, 3) + ' ' + cast(year(GETDATE()) as varchar(4))