# select between two dates based on month and year periodic mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

How do I implement the MySQL for selecting data between. Let say I have a variable:

```
$dateA = '2014-06-25'
$dateB = '2014-08-26'
```

I make an example MySQL syntax like this:

```
"select * from table where dateA >= $dateA and dateB <= $dateB"
```

So I want to make a selection to MySQL using those 2 dates based on the month and year only not including the date itself:

Any ideas about this?

**UPDATE**

For example all I want to do is like this basically:

```
"select * from table where dateA >= '2014-06' and dateB <= '2014-08'"
```

That's basically what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting only Month and Year from SQL DATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date)

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you mean that query would be `select * from table where dateA >= 20140701 and dateB < 20140801`? Or do you mean select between the months given in the dates but not those exact days? Can you give an expected example string that would be created?

Comment: @Popnoodles I updated the question you could see the example above thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You can use a string comparison.

`DATE_FORMAT(dateA,'%Y%m')` should return dates like: 201406.  You would also need to change the format of your variables or use the same method on them.

```
where DATE_FORMAT(dateA,'%Y%m') >= DATE_FORMAT($dateA,'%Y%m') and 
DATE_FORMAT(dateB,'%Y%m') <= DATE_FORMAT($dateB,'%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from table
where dateA between date_format( $dateA, '%y-%m-01' ) and last_day( $dateB );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where YEAR(dateA) > YEAR($dateA) and YEAR(dateB) < YEAR($dateB) 
    AND MONTH(dateA) > MONTH($dateA) and MONTH(dateB) < MONTH($dateB)
```

Theres probalby something much more efficient out there, bt this will do too

Answer (score 0):

i suggest making the change in php as this enables mysql query cache for wider range of inputs:

```
$dateA = date("Y-m-01", strtotime('2014-06-25'));
$dateB = date("Y-m-t", strtotime('2014-08-26'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateA = '2014-06-25';
$dateB = '2014-08-26';
$dateA_month = '2014-02-01';
$dateB_month = '2014-02-31';
"select * from table where dateA >= $dateA_month and dateB <= $dateB_month";
```

I wrote the exmaple on purpose with february. This selector works well even is the month in question does not end with 31th. Expecting downvotes from calendar-fans:)

Comment: try using your codes and it works well ! yeah why I haven't thought about it before. my mistakes, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Use the following SQL Statement for selecting the data between the two date:-

```
$dateA = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-06-25'));
$dateB = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-08-26'));


SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') 

BETWEEN $dateA AND $dateB;
```

Comment: That would make the query non-sargable and would cause a complete table scan as the date_created field of every row must be examined -- even if it is indexed. The solution must not manipulate the field itself -- like `date_created between date_format( $date_a, '%y-%m-01 ) and last_day( $date_b )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
WHERE (someField BETWEEN '2016-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2016-09-29 10:15:55')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
"select * from table where [datetime_column] between " . $dateA . " and " .$dataB
```

Comment: which would include the dates. *"...not including the date it self"*

Comment: my point exactly @Popnoodles, but I appreciate for your help thanks ! Melvin Koopmans