# Loading every day in a month from a database

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a calendar program that can contain up to 6 events per day. Currently the software uses a for loop to check everyday for events. 
This takes time as it opens and closes the mysql connection 31 times. 
The method works and it only takes about 1 second per loop, im just looking for a better method, if there is one.

```
 For i As Integer = 1 To 31
                If (i = 32) Then
                    Exit For
                    Main.Hide()



                End If

                Try
                    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
                    Dim dbConn As New MySqlConnection
                    Dim dbQuery As String = ""
                    Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand
                    Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
                    Dim dbTable As New DataTable
                    Dim count As Integer

    If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                        dbConn.ConnectionString = "Database=###########;Data Source=###########;User Id=###########;Password=###########;Connection Timeout=20"
                        dbConn.Open()
                    End If
                    count = 0
                    dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM ########### WHERE date='" & numericMonth & "/" & i & "/" & numericYear & "'"


                    With dbCmd
                        .CommandText = dbQuery
                        .Connection = dbConn
                    End With
                    With dbAdapter
                        .SelectCommand = dbCmd
                        .Fill(dbTable)
                    End With

                    '/// Start Event Counter

                    reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader
                    count = 0
                    While reader.Read
                        count = count + 1
                    End While



                    '/////// If Day Contains 1 Event

                    If count = 1 Then
                        Dim date1 = New CustomEvent()
                        Dim bgColor1 As Color = Color.FromName(dbTable.Rows(0).Item(16).ToString())
                        Dim fontColor1 As Color = Color.FromName(dbTable.Rows(0).Item(17).ToString())

                        '///Event 1

                        date1.IgnoreTimeComponent = True
                        date1.EventText = dbTable.Rows(0).Item(5).ToString()
                        date1.Date = numericYear & "," & numericMonth & "," & i
                        date1.RecurringFrequency = RecurringFrequencies.None
                        date1.EventFont = New Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
                        date1.EventColor = bgColor1
                        date1.Enabled = True
                        Calendar1.AddEvent(date1)

                        '/// If Day Contains 2 Events

                         #####More Events

                        '/// If Day Contains 3 Events

                    ElseIf count = 3 Then

            #####More Events

                        '/// If Day Contains 4 Events

                    ElseIf count = 4 Then

                        #####More Events

                        '/// If Day Contains 5 Events

                    ElseIf count = 5 Then

                        #####More Events

                        '/// If Day Contains 6 Events

                    ElseIf count = 6 Then

            #####More Events

                    End If



                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                                vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 8888.")
                    Application.Exit()

                End Try
                Main.ProgressBar1.Value = Main.ProgressBar1.Value + 3

            Next
        Else
        End If
```

Comment: `where date between start_date and end_date`

Comment: That query checks everyday of the month, for instance , the 1st loop would be 
WHERE date='" & numericMonth & "/" & i & "/" & numericYear & "'" Or assuming the month selected was june and the year was 2015
WHERE date='" 06/1/2015"

Comment: Isn't that what you want?  That's one call to the database.  Use parameters, by the way, to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: i added the for statement maybe that will make it more clear, it will connect to the DB 31 times to get all the days.

Comment: Why are you making 31 calls to the database?  Just use `between` as @LarsTech said.

Comment: If i use the between will it just populate the dtable with all the events from the dates selected? if so i would most likely need to hard code 6 events for each day, currently the loop adds the events as it goes.

Comment: Why would you have to hard-code anything at all?  You make one call to the database, then you can loop through your result set.

Comment: Or, just [check the year and month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date), ignore the day.

Comment: I dont understand how i would check against the DataTable and still have each date checked for up to 6 events.

Comment: Well, order the query by date.  When you get a different date, reset the counter back to zero, repeat.  It means getting rid of your for-loop.