# get only month and year from date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want get only year, and only numeric month from date, I try this for month by i get char month, how can i get numeric month, and year ?

```
select to_char(dateper,'MON') 
from calcul
 group by dateper
```

Comment: An useful reference - stackoverflow.com/a/29839100/3682599 and a sample - http://hastebin.com/ewaxotacul.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a numeric representation in a string by using:

```
select extract(year from dateper) as yyyy, extract(month from dateper) as mm
from calcul
group by yyyy, mm;
```

Or:

```
select to_char(dateper, 'YYYY-MM') 
from calcul
group by to_char(dateper, 'YYYY-MM') ;
```

Comment: it return year function don't exist

Comment: @khadi8 . . . Ooops.  I forgot that I have those functions defined in my local version of Postgres.  Those are my functions, not Postgres's.  The correct function is `extract()`, which is the ANSI standard function for this.

Answer (score 1):

Month:

```
SELECT date_part('month', now())::integer;
```

Year:

```
SELECT date_part('year', now())::integer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
datename(m,column)+' '+cast(datepart(yyyy,column) as varchar) as MonthYear
```

or

```
select to_char(DATEFIELD,'MON') from YOUR_TABLE
```

please Refer This Page

[See The Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date)

Comment: This is invalid for Postgres: string concatenation is done using `||` in SQL and there is neither a `datepart()` nor a `datename()` in Postgres