# Convert the date format in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to take date without day.. 
Example I get a date like '28-07-2015',and I need to convert it to like '00-07-2015'.
When am inserting the date to a particular table.

Comment: `mysql || sql server` ?

Comment: If it is mysql you could use EXTRACT() and then assmeble the parts http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_extract.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cast('00-' as varchar) + cast( month(getdate()) as varchar) +'-'+ cast(year(getdate()) as varchar)
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response. But here I want to return the value either as 'date' format or 'datetime' format.All the above solutions are in 'varchar' format. Please Help me if u can.

Comment: 00 cannot be converted to date or datetime. If you need 00, you need to convert to varchar. You can use this query  "select cast( month(getdate()) as varchar) +'-'+ cast(year(getdate()) as varchar)  " to get the month and date only.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1**

If you are using `SQL server` you can do like below

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, <dateField>), 0) AS [year_month_date_field]
  FROM <your_table>
```

**SOLUTION 2**

you can simply `SELECT` it like below:-

```
Select cast( month(getdate()) as varchar) +'-'+ cast(year(getdate()) as varchar) as DateWithoutDay
```

**SOLUTION 3**

You can also do something like this

```
SELECT convert(varchar(7), getdate(), 126)
```

which gives result as

[image: Result for date]

For more information [See the link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date)