# how to Select getdate () in yyyy/M format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to select `getdate()` in the format `yyyy/M`. I tried to write a query

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy/M')
```

but it is throwing an error.

I am a beginner in SQL. How do I get the `yyyy/m` format if there is only single digit month? E.g. the query should return `2016/1` when there is only one digit month (it should not return `2016/01`) and should return `2016/10` when the month has two digits

Comment: Seems like the answer could be gleaned from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date

Answer (score 4):

How about getting the `YEAR` and `MONTH` part of the date and just concatenate them:

```
SELECT
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' +
    CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

Comment: Purely out of curiousity, why not use `CONCAT` instead of `CAST` and `+`?

Comment: I don't think `CONCAT` is available on sql server 2008.

Comment: Ah. I guess I've been spoiled by 2012

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

<strike>SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy/MM')</strike>

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2015-11-15' AS smalldatetime),'yyyy/M'), 
      FORMAT(CAST('2015-01-15' AS smalldatetime),'yyyy/M')
```

Gives:

```
2015/11 | 2015/1
```

Comment: :( currently on 2014 and don't have access to 2008

Comment: `FORMAT` is a **new feature** in SQL Server 2012 and therefore not available in 2005 or 2008.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM]
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 111)
```