# Oracle to SQL Server: Month + Year where clause

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, to-char

I have an Oracle Query that goes as follow:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
    AND to_char(a.bill_Date, 'MMYYYY') = '072017'
    ...
ORDER BY ...
```

In SQL Server, we have the MONTH() and YEAR() functions.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
    AND MONTH(a.BILL_DATE) = MONTH(GETDATE())
    AND YEAR(a.BILL_DATE) =  YEAR(GETDATE())
    ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Is there something that allows me to apply a Month-Year constraint like Oracle does with to_char through a single step? I have to make this parameterized and maintain compatibility with both databases through a common interface. Now, one would require two parameters and other would just one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting only Month and Year from SQL DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date)

Comment: Not as far as I know.  The closest thing to Oracle's `TO_CHAR()` function would be SQL Server's `CONVERT()`.  But this would generate a string with a day component.

Comment: I started off with CONVERT and ended up with a complex clause. You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest thing to Oracle's `TO_CHAR` function in SQL Server would be `CONVERT`.  But even with `CONVERT` I see no option to request only the year and month.  Rather, we would need to accept at least the day as well, and possibly a timestamp in addition to this.

`CONVERT` accepts a date format mask parameter as its third argument.  The `112` mask returns a date only in the following format:

```
yyyymmdd
```

So for the date in your question it would return this:

```
201707dd
```

where I have left `dd` undefined as I don't know which day a given record might have.  Now we can get close to what you want by taking the left 6 characters of this output, e.g.

```
WHERE ... AND
    LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, a.bill_Date, 112), 6) = '201707'
```

Comment: Aim is to get data for the whole month. Don't want to attempt a BETWEEN

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `BETWEEN` and in fact I believe that both `TO_CHAR` and `CONVERT` may preclude the possibility of using an index on your date column.  Given your other constraints, this may be your only option, but it might not be the most performant one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would say that in SQL Server `FORMAT` is closest to `TO_CHAR` :)

Answer (score 3):

To get year and month in SQL Server (2012 and above) you could use [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql):

> FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )

```
WHERE ...
  AND FORMAT(a.bill_Date, 'yyyyMM') = '201707';

--or

WHERE ...
  AND FORMAT(a.bill_Date, 'MMyyyy') = '072017';
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/PRN65171)**

Please keep in mind that `FORMAT(a.bil_Date, 'MMyyyy')` is not SARG-able so there will be no index usage.

Comment: Good answer, didn't think of using `FORMAT` +1

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your Oracle query to avoid data to char conversions:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
    AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM a.bill_Date) = 7 
    AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM a.bill_Date) = 2017 
    ...
ORDER BY ...
```

and the equivalent SQL Server

```
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
WHERE ...
        AND MONTH(a.bill_Date) = 7 
        AND YEAR(a.bill_Date) = 2017 
        ... 
ORDER BY ...
```