# How extract only month name from database

Tags: php, sql

```
$m = squery("SELECT  date FROM attendance WHERE id=7"
```

This query returns array of dates..
I Want to extract only month name from this array..
Thanxs.

Comment: What type of field is `date`?

Comment: What is the datatype of your `date` column?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date

Comment: `select monthname( date )`??

Comment: @ RamRaider its returning array..

Comment: like 30 days one month ..

Comment: What is the data type of your date column? is it varchar, datetime, timestamp, int?

Comment: @ hungrykoala its date time

Comment: Read this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36852/how-to-get-only-month-from-mysql-date-time

Comment: You can use DATE_FORMAT for that. 
"SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`date` , '%M') AS `date` FROM attendance WHERE id=7"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your date column is of type `date` then,

Let a dummy table data be as follows,

**Table**

```
+------+------------+
| id   | DDate      |
+------+------------+
|    7 | 2018-06-21 |
|    7 | 2018-06-22 |
|    7 | 2018-06-23 |
|    7 | 2018-06-24 |
|    7 | 2018-06-25 |
|    7 | 2018-06-26 |
+------+------------+
```

**Query 1** : to get the month number

```
select month(DDate) as Mnth from MBO where id=7 group by Mnth;
+------+
| Mnth |
+------+
|    6 |
+------+
```

**Query 2** : To get month name

```
select monthname(DDate) as Mnth from MBO where id=7 group by Mnth;
+------+
| Mnth |
+------+
| June |
+------+
```

You can change your SQL as above to assign your variable to desired value,

*Note:* it is assumed that for `id=7` a single month dates would be present in table hence added a `group by` to get unique value. Else you may need to add more conditions to get a single value, or if you just need to get any month then a `limit 1` will do.

Comment: Good to hear .. Happy to help .. :) @Sachin

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo $date = date('j M Y ', strtotime($row['date']));
```

day=j, month=M, year=Y

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: Its array with dates and with the month

Answer (score 1):

Use DATE_FORMAT function

```
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date` , '%M') AS `month_name` FROM `attendance` WHERE id=7 group by month_name"
```