# extract year and month from date field mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

How can I get year and month values only as `yyyy-mm` format from `datetime` field?

I tried

```
Select EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH From task_completion) from task;
```

But this results in `201901` format.

Also I tried this solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date):

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, task_completion), 0)
FROM task
```

Which gives `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'` error, since this was solution for `sql-server`.

Is there any equivalent solution for mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(year(task_completion), '-' ,month(task_completion)) FROM task
```

Answer (score 6):

year and month function in mysql

```
select year(task_completion),month(task_completion) from task
```

but if you need year with month use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
 select  DATE_FORMAT(task_completion,'%Y-%m') from task
```

Comment: @Azima eidted answer

Comment: had to improvise a bit.. '%Y-%m'

Comment: @Azima . . . `date_format()` is the right way to do what you want.  Presumably, you want `2019-01` and not `2019-1`, which is why this is the better solution.